# Appending Co-Ordinates to a list as integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is,

```
n = int(input("Enter the Number of Lines : "))
s = []
c = []

for i in range(2): #n=2
    m = int(input("Line's Number : "))
    s.append(m)
    c.append(input("Enter Co-ordinates : ").split())
```

input line 1: (1,2),(3,4)
input line 2: (6,7),(9,0)

output should be : [[1,3,6,9],[2,4,7,0]]

Comment: use `ast.literal_eval` and `zip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a lot of transpositions going on here. I fiddled a bit with `ast.literal_eval` (to evaluate the tuples) and then a few `zip` calls, maybe there's something simpler:

```
import ast

for m,i in enumerate(["(1,2),(3,4)","(6,7),(9,0)"]):  # hardcoded the input
    s.append(m)
    c.append(zip(*ast.literal_eval(i)))

result = [a+b for a,b in zip(*c)]
```

result:

```
[(1, 3, 6, 9), (2, 4, 7, 0)]
```

Comment: Downvote? There is an explanation and it works. Yeah, that must be the reason, then.